# How to use the adapter pattern, while getting typing support

Tags: python, adapter, python-typing, python-dataclasses, pylance

Given this code:

```py
class ComponentType(StrEnum):
    container = auto()
    form = auto()
    fieldset = auto()
    # more enum values....

@dataclass()
class Component():
    # Common fields for all components
    id: str | None = None
    type: ComponentType | None = None
    parent: Union['Component', None] = None
    children: List['Component'] = field(default_factory=list)

    # reference to the json object this Component was parsed from
    json_reference: dict[str, Any] | None = None

    # For type specific fields
    additional_fields: dict[str, Any] = field(default_factory=dict)


@dataclass
class FieldComponent:
    def __init__(self, component: Component) -> None:
        self.component = component

    def __getattr__(self, item: str):
        return getattr(self.component, item)

    def get_field_label(self) -> str | None:
        return self.additional_fields.get('fieldLabel')

    def set_field_label(self, field_label: str):
        self.additional_fields['fieldLabel'] = field_label


FieldComponentType = FieldComponent | Component
```

I am wrapping a dataclass `Component` in `FieldComponent` using `__getattr__`. I am able to use all `FieldComponent` instances where a `Component` instance is expected. So the adapter functionality itself works fine at runtime. However, I'd like properly get suppoort for intellisense by using typing. But pylance in vscode warns me about the types being incompatible when trying to return a `FieldComponent` where a `Component` is expected.

```py
def foo(field_component: FieldComponent) -> Component:
    return field_component
```

[image]

Another issue is that intellisense does not work properly for the wrapper class.

```py
def foo(comp: Component) -> Component:
    comp.id         # Intellisense works fine, is direct member of Component
    comp.children   # Intellisense works fine, is direct member of Component
    comp.get_field_label() # Could work at runtine, but gives typing error, this behaviour is fine

    field_component = cast(FieldComponent, comp)
    field_component.get_field_label() # Intellisense works, is direct member of FieldComponent class
    field_component.id  # Intellisense does not work, even though this attribute is available by __getattr__

    # I already tried working around this with a Union type, this does not work
    union_component = cast(FieldComponent | Component, comp)
    union_component.name # Works fine, is member of Component
    union_component.get_field_label() # Pylance: Cannot access member "get_field_label" for type "Component"
```

So I guess my question is, how can I write an adapter class, that wraps a static set of fields and also get support by the type system?